# How do I limit permissions for "Valid Users" but allow more permissive ones for groups like Contributors/custom?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm new to DevOps, and everything but the permissions settings has been intuitive. From what I gather, every user is automatically added to "Project Collection Valid Users", and then in a given project, it looks like every group & user is also automatically added to the "Project Valid Users" group, which inherits from "Project Collection Valid Users". Clearly, you don't want to grant "Allow" access to everything for the generic Valid Users group (both project/org). But I'm confused, because if I look at say the "Contributors" group for a project, it says it is a member of "Project Valid Users" which therefore means it inherits those permissions. The confusion arises from their descriptions in the portal.

"Project Valid Users" is described as "Members of this group have access to the team project." That sounds like it's MORE restrictive than the Contributors group which says, "Members of this group can add, modify, and delete items within the team project." Yet, since Contributors is a member of Project Valid Users, I can't override any Deny settings since due to inheritance, Deny at the upper level trumps Allow at the sub level.

This is even more confusing if I add my own group, at say the organization level: it's automatically added to "Project Collection Valid Users" which means it will inherit all Deny settings and I can't make this new group more permissive, if I needed to for a certain situation.

What I'm trying to achieve is to limit the scope of the default generic valid users group, but at the same time allow for say custom groups to have more permissive settings (like for being able to control security access to specific repositories, or to have more permissive settings for "higher" tier employees with greater project responsibilities). I don't understand how to achieve this without just assigning people to the admin group, which isn't a good idea in every situation. Or without marking everything as "Allow" in valid users and then for every single group that derives from it, marking "Deny" where needed.

I have a feeling I'm completely misunderstanding something fundamental, but I'm not able to gain any insight from the DevOps docs that helps me understand from a brand new user's perspective.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Use the "not set" permission for permissions that you want to be overridden at a different scope. "Not set" means "deny *if not explicitly allowed*. "Deny" means "never allow, under any circumstances"

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know how to set your reply as the answer, but that never occurred to me to try "Not Set". I again, misinterpreted things and presumed it would default to "Deny", not realizing it meant what you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "not set" permission for permissions that you want to be overridden at a different scope. "Not set" means "deny *if not explicitly allowed*. "Deny" means "never allow, under any circumstances"